# Migrating to Xcode and now having lots of "is not member of std" and some other header problems

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, header, g++

I am migrating to OS X and now trying to use Xcode.
There is a project that was compiling and running normally on a g++ linux distro, now on mac it is returning a thousand of errors. I guess that the linux std files, somehow included others files needed and now they are not this connected in the std of Mac OS X.
How can I know what I am doing wrong, like here:

```
/Users/Jonathan/Development/C++/Josk/Var.h:257:0 No match for 'operator<<' in 'out << ((Josk::Var*)Jv)->Josk::Var::ToString()' in /Users/Jonathan/Development/C++/Josk/Var.h
```

the code is:

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream &out, Josk::Var &Jv){
  out << Jv.ToString();
return out;
}
```

I don't know what to add here to solve this,
here are the actual includes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
```

Thanks!
  Jonathan

Comment: Mac OS x uses gcc as well, what version were you using on Linux?

Comment: Standard library classes are in the namespace `std`. Do you have a `using namespace std;` somewhere? (Bad!)

Comment: What is the first of these errors, and which piece of code causes it? In C++, many errors are just follow-up errors that are caused by an earlier error.

@samm: The Linux STL does include some nonstandard extensions that are not available on OS X, e.g. `std::bit_xor`. However, I doubt this could cause thousands of errors.

Comment: Try compiling a simple "Hello World" program using say std::cout - does that work?

Comment: @samm: I can't see the version right now, as soon I can, I post here. @GMan: No, I don't use using keyword in any place, not for standard, not for my own classes. @Philipp: The error above is the first one, there are just 8 errors now, they are all the same, because I removed some files just to see a little less errors so I can walk through them easily. @Mark: I did some test and it is working fine, the problem seems to be in the header files. THanks for all comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing `#include <string>`.

Comment: Seems reasonable. `<ostream>` doesn't contain an overload for `operator<<(basic_ostream, basic_string)`. But then I wonder what the return type of `Jv.ToString` is.

Comment: True, with the include of string, it worked. But How would I know that this specific include would help me? Philipp: ToString returns a const char *.

Comment: The reason it works is that std::string has a non-explicit constructor with `const char*` as it's only argument. Which means it's an automatic conversion.

I don't know how you would know, apart from making the connection between string and const char*.